# java npm gives "\\node_modules\\java\\build\\Release\\nodejavabridge_bindings.node","stack":"Error: The specified module could not be found." error

Tags: javascript, java, npm

I have a requirement where I need to perform some java tasks in my nodejs app.
My application is on node version 12.22.7 with java 8 installed on 64 bit windows machine
I have installed java npm version ^0.12.1. But while trying to run the application it throws the following error
"\node_modules\java\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.node","stack":"Error: The specified module could not be found."
I have checked and the file exists in the above path
Is there any work around for it?